# Generating an optimal binary search tree (Cormen)

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming

I'm reading Cormen et al., *Introduction to Algorithms* (3rd ed.) ([PDF](https://github.com/yuanhui-yang/Introduction-to-Algorithms/blob/master/Introduction%20to%20Algorithms%20-%203rd%20Edition.pdf)), section 15.4 on optimal binary search trees, but am having some trouble implementing the pseudocode for the `optimal_bst` function in Python.

Here is the example I'm trying to apply the optimal BST to:

[image]

Let us define `e[i,j]` as the expected cost of searching an optimal binary search tree containing the keys labeled from `i` to `j`. Ultimately, we wish to compute `e[1, n]`, where `n` is the number of keys (5 in this example). The final recursive formulation is:

[image]

which should be implemented by the following pseudocode:

[image]

Notice that the pseudocode interchangeably uses 1- and 0-based indexing, whereas Python uses only the latter. As a consequence I'm having trouble implementing the pseudocode. Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

p = [0.15, 0.10, 0.05, 0.10, 0.20]
q = [0.05, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.10]
n = len(p)

e = np.diag(q)
w = np.diag(q)
root = np.zeros((n, n))
for l in range(1, n+1):
    for i in range(n-l+1):
        j = i + l
        e[i, j] = np.inf
        w[i, j] = w[i, j-1] + p[j-1] + q[j]
        for r in range(i, j+1):
            t = e[i-1, r-1] + e[r, j] + w[i-1, j]
            if t < e[i-1, j]:
                e[i-1, j] = t
                root[i-1, j] = r

print(w)
print(e)
```

However, if I run this the weights `w` get computed correctly, but the expected search values `e` remain 'stuck' at their initialized values:

```
[[ 0.05  0.3   0.45  0.55  0.7   1.  ]
 [ 0.    0.1   0.25  0.35  0.5   0.8 ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.05  0.15  0.3   0.6 ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.05  0.2   0.5 ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.05  0.35]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.1 ]]
[[ 0.05   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf]
 [ 0.    0.1    inf   inf   inf   inf]
 [ 0.    0.    0.05   inf   inf   inf]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.05   inf   inf]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.05   inf]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.1 ]]
```

What I expect is that `e`, `w`, and `root` be as follows:

[image]

I've been debugging this for a couple of hours by now and am still stuck. Can someone point out what is wrong with the Python code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)' `Series` and `DataFrame` objects initialized with custom `index` and `columns` to coerce the arrays to have the same indexing as in the pseudocode. After that, the pseudocode can be almost copy-pasted:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

P = [0.15, 0.10, 0.05, 0.10, 0.20]
Q = [0.05, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.10]
n = len(P)

p = pd.Series(P, index=range(1, n+1))
q = pd.Series(Q)

e = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(Q), index=range(1, n+2))
w = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(Q), index=range(1, n+2))
root = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((n, n)), index=range(1, n+1), columns=range(1, n+1))

for l in range(1, n+1):
    for i in range(1, n-l+2):
        j = i+l-1
        e.set_value(i, j, np.inf)
        w.set_value(i, j, w.get_value(i, j-1) + p[j] + q[j])
        for r in range(i, j+1):
            t = e.get_value(i, r-1) + e.get_value(r+1, j) + w.get_value(i, j)
            if t < e.get_value(i, j):
                e.set_value(i, j, t)
                root.set_value(i, j, r)

print(e)
print(w)
print(root)
```

which yields the expected results:

```
      0     1     2     3     4     5
1  0.05  0.45  0.90  1.25  1.75  2.75
2  0.00  0.10  0.40  0.70  1.20  2.00
3  0.00  0.00  0.05  0.25  0.60  1.30
4  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.05  0.30  0.90
5  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.05  0.50
6  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.10
      0    1     2     3     4     5
1  0.05  0.3  0.45  0.55  0.70  1.00
2  0.00  0.1  0.25  0.35  0.50  0.80
3  0.00  0.0  0.05  0.15  0.30  0.60
4  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.05  0.20  0.50
5  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.05  0.35
6  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.10
     1    2    3    4    5
1  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
2  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  4.0
3  0.0  0.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  5.0
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  5.0
```

I would still be interested in a solution with Numpy arrays, though, as this seems more elegant to me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you made a mistake in the indices. I couldn't make it work as expected but the following code should give you an indication where I was heading at (there is probably an off by one somewhere):

```
import numpy as np

p = [0.15, 0.10, 0.05, 0.10, 0.20]
q = [0.05, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.10]
n = len(p)

def get2(m, i, j):
    return m[i - 1, j - 1]


def set2(m, i, j, v):
    m[i - 1, j - 1] = v


def get1(m, i):
    return m[i - 1]


def set1(m, i, v):
    m[i - 1] = v


e = np.diag(q)
w = np.diag(q)
root = np.zeros((n, n))
for l in range(1, n + 1):
    for i in range(n - l + 2):
        j = i + l - 1
        set2(e, i, j, np.inf)
        set2(w, i, j, get2(w, i, j - 1) + get1(p, j) + get1(q, j))
        for r in range(i, j + 1):
            t = get2(e, i, r - 1) + get2(e, r + 1, j) + get2(w, i, j)
            if t < get2(e, i, j):
                set2(e, i, j, t)
                set2(root, i, j, r)

print(w)
print(e)
```

The result:

```
[[ 0.2   0.4   0.5   0.65  0.9   0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.2   0.3   0.45  0.7   0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.1   0.25  0.5   0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.15  0.4   0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.25  0.  ]
 [ 0.5   0.7   0.8   0.95  0.    0.3 ]]
[[ 0.2   0.6   0.8   1.2   1.95  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.2   0.4   0.8   1.35  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.1   0.35  0.85  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.15  0.55  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.25  0.  ]
 [ 0.7   1.2   1.5   2.    0.    0.3 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Kurt,
Thanks for your post! Yours is the only working implementation of this problem I found. I spent mucho tiempo wrestling with the indices. Here is my implementation with numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import math

def optimalBST(p,q,n):

    e = np.zeros((n+1)**2).reshape(n+1,n+1)
    w = np.zeros((n+1)**2).reshape(n+1,n+1)
    root = np.zeros((n+1)**2).reshape(n+1,n+1)

    # Initialization
    for i in range(n+1):
        e[i,i] = q[i]
        w[i,i] = q[i]
    for i in range(0,n):
        root[i,i] = i+1

    for l in range(1,n+1):
        for i in range(0, n-l+1):
            j = i+l
            min_ = math.inf
            w[i,j] = w[i,j-1] + p[j] + q[j]
            for r in range(i,j):
                t = e[i, r-1+1] + e[r+1,j] +  w[i,j]
                if t < min_:
                    min_ = t                
                    e[i, j] = t
                    root[i, j-1] = r+1

    root_pruned = np.delete(np.delete(root, n, 1), n, 0)        # Trim last col & row.

    print("------ e -------")
    print(e)
    print("------ w -------")
    print(w)
    print("----- root -----")
    print(root_pruned)

def main():

    p = [0,.15,.1,.05,.1,.2]
    q = [.05,.1,.05,.05,.05,.1]
    n = len(p)-1

    optimalBST(p,q,n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
------ e -------
[[0.05 0.45 0.9  1.25 1.75 2.75]
 [0.   0.1  0.4  0.7  1.2  2.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.05 0.25 0.6  1.3 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.05 0.3  0.9 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.05 0.5 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.1 ]]
------ w -------
[[0.05 0.3  0.45 0.55 0.7  1.  ]
 [0.   0.1  0.25 0.35 0.5  0.8 ]
 [0.   0.   0.05 0.15 0.3  0.6 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.05 0.2  0.5 ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.05 0.35]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.1 ]]
----- root -----
[[1. 1. 2. 2. 2.]
 [0. 2. 2. 2. 4.]
 [0. 0. 3. 4. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0. 4. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 5.]]
```